# How to display dynamically and image?

Tags: python, flask, keras

Hello I am making an small page to show my results I am working in a project about sentiment analysis first I have the following labels:

```
senti=["furious","angry","angry0","Indiferent","happy","enthusiastic","Euphoric"]
```

I show this labels depending of the result of a predict function that I performed using keras, at this moment all is working well I wish to show an image depending of the label of above I tried creating an array with the path of the images as follows, I am not sure how to write the image function,

```
images=['home/image0.jpg','home/image1.jpg','home/image2.jpg','home/image3.jpg','home/image4.jpg','home/image5.jpg','home/image6.jpg']
def image():
```

This is the function that perform the predict, at this moment it is just showing a label of above, I would like to also display a distinct image, so I need to modify the following function:

```
def predict(text):
    seqs = tok.texts_to_sequences([text])
    print(text)
    word_index = tok.word_index
    print('Found %s unique tokens.' % len(word_index))
    sequence_pred = sequence.pad_sequences(seqs, maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)
    print(sequence_pred)
    prediction = model.predict(sequence_pred)
    print(prediction)
    return senti[np.argmax(prediction[0])]

    @app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def index():
        print(request.method)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            q=request.form['querytext']
            prediction=predict(q)
            return render_template("result.html",prediction=prediction,text=q)
        return render_template("main.html")
```

Since I am a beginner at flask I would like to appreciate support or suggestions to overcome this situation thanks for the help,

After a very useful feedback I tried:

```
senti=["furious","angry","angry0","Indiferent","happy","enthusiastic","Euphoric"]


def predict(text):
    seqs = tok.texts_to_sequences([text])
    print(text)
    word_index = tok.word_index
    print('Found %s unique tokens.' % len(word_index))
    sequence_pred = sequence.pad_sequences(seqs, maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)
    print(sequence_pred)
    prediction = model.predict(sequence_pred)
    print(prediction)
    return senti[np.argmax(prediction[0])]

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    senti=["furious","angry","angry0","Indiferent","happy","enthusiastic","Euphoric"]
    images=['smile.jpg','smile.jpg','smile.jpg','smile.jpg','smile.jpg','smile.jpg','smile.jpg']
    lookup_keys = dict(zip(senti, images))
    print(request.method)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        q=request.form['querytext']
        prediction=predict(q)
        image_path = lookup_keys[prediction] # get the path
        return render_template("result.html",
                               prediction=prediction,
                               text=q,
                               image_url=image_path)
    return render_template("main.html")
```

I am not getting any error but the image is not displayed I am not so sure what is wrong, at this moment I am just trying with one image located at the same level of my file called app.py, smile.jpg

```
$ ls
app.py smile.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a dictionary of your keys and the image values; and use that to return the image for the particular sentiment:

```
>>> senti=["furious","angry","angry0","Indiferent","happy","enthusiastic","Euphoric"]
>>> images=['home/image0.jpg','home/image1.jpg','home/image2.jpg','home/image3.jpg','home/image4.jpg','home/image5.jpg','home/image6.jpg']
>>> dict(zip(senti, images))
{'enthusiastic': 'home/image5.jpg', 'Indiferent': 'home/image3.jpg', 'furious': 'home/image0.jpg', 'Euphoric': 'home/image6.jpg', 'angry': 'home/image1.jpg', 'happy': 'home/image4.jpg', 'angry0': 'home/image2.jpg'}
>>> lookup_values = dict(zip(senti, images))
>>> lookup_values['angry']
'home/image1.jpg'
```

You can use this in your view method, to get the right image path and the send it to the template:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    senti=["furious","angry","angry0","Indiferent","happy","enthusiastic","Euphoric"]
    images=['home/image0.jpg','home/image1.jpg','home/image2.jpg','home/image3.jpg','home/image4.jpg','home/image5.jpg','home/image6.jpg']
    lookup_keys = dict(zip(senti, images))
    print(request.method)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        q=request.form['querytext']
        prediction=predict(q)
        image_path = lookup_keys[prediction] # get the path
        return render_template("result.html",
                               prediction=prediction,
                               text=q,
                               image_url=image_path)
    return render_template("main.html")
```

Comment: thanks it was very useful I have a question I tried this method but the image is not being displayed I dont get any error so I am not sure what is wrong I update the question,

Comment: Please read [the flask documentation on static files.](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#static-files)

Comment: yes I will read it, I was not aware that I need to modify my file called result.html to show the image thanks for the support